# AlertDialog single choice item padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I want to add top and bottom padding between each single choice item in an AlertDialog. I have attempted to achieve this goal with this `style` resource:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_button_background_selector</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">17dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">17dp</item>
</style>
```

Then the `Activity` code that uses this `style` is pretty straightforward:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDialog)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(options, currentSelectedIndex) { dialog, index ->
            if (index != currentSelectedIndex) {
                // do something
            }

            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        .show()
```

The padding works as expected, except that it also adds a huge margin at the top and bottom of the `DialogFragment`.

How can I add padding between each single choice item without having this unintended consequence?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the `paddingTop` and the `paddingBottom` in the entire `Dialog`.

With an **`AppCompat`** theme you can use a theme overlay like:

```
<style name="customLMultiItem" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- if you want to remove the indicator in each row -->
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@null</item> 
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/my.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="my.AlertDialog" parent="AlertDialog.AppCompat">
    <!-- to use a custom layout for the singlechoice -->
    <item name="singleChoiceItemLayout">@layout/my_dialog_singlechoice</item>
</style>
```

In this way you can use a custom layout (copied from the original + the padding):

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@android:id/text1"
                 android:paddingTop="XXdp"
                 android:paddingBottom="Xdp"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:textColor="?attr/textColorAlertDialogListItem"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_select_dialog_padding_start_material"
                 android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                 android:paddingStart="@dimen/abc_select_dialog_padding_start_material"
                 android:paddingEnd="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                 android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                 android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                 android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Then just use `AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.customLMultiItem)`.

[image]

With a **`MaterialComponents`** Theme:

```
<style name="customLMultiItem" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@null</item>
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/my.MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents</item>
</style>

<style name="my.MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="singleChoiceItemLayout">@layout/my_dialog_singlechoice</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: After adding those 2 `style` and 1 `layout` resources, it doesn't look like the `layout` resource's `CheckedTextView` is being used when I render the dialog. It appears to be defaulting to default Android layout instead. The code I use to render the dialog in the activity is in the original question, if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you share your activity code? My code is not picking up the `CheckedTextView` layout file.

Comment: @freezefry Nothing special. Just `AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.customLMultiItem)` or `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,R.style.customLMultiItem)`