# Set AlertDialog View Inset via style

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-xml

I use Acr.UserDialogs to create cross-platform dialogs from a Xamarin Shared/PCL project. Acr.UserDialogs contains a method to create a prompt which (in Android) is an AlertDialog whose View is set to an EditText. Unfortunately the View/EditText has no margin/padding which results in it reaching until the outer left and right limits of the dialog - which looks pretty ugly. Due to it being a library I have no ability to change how exactly the EditText or the AlertDialog are created (rather than editing the libraries code on GitHub myself but that's a way I try to avoid for now if possible). What the library supports is the possibility to pass an AndroidStyleId into the call that it uses instead of the default Android AlertDialog style (`new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, passedAndroidStyleId)`).

Now, my idea is to create a style that defines a custom margin/padding/inset to the View of the AlertDialog kind of as follows and pass it in.

```
<style name="CustomPromptDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="viewInset">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Problem is I can't find any resources listing which "properties" can be set in a style or how they are named, so my only idea was to ask here:
Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style like this to change the form of the `Alertdialog`. This the method for globel setting.

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.picker</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.alert</item>
</style>
    
    <style name="Theme.alert" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
         <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="viewInset">10dp</item>
```

Comment: I know how I can set the style. I even wrote it in my question that the library has a way to set it besides changing its style globally. Also you added things like colorAccent and background color which I'm aware of. I specifically asked if there is an attribute to add an inset to the AlertDialog's View via style. In my example "viewInset" was only a placeholder to describe how I think it should be used, if something like that exists. "viewInset" itself is not a recognized attribute, that's why I'm asking if there is one that works as I need it to.

Comment: you can try android:paddingTop="XXdp" android:paddingBottom="Xdp" android:drawablePadding="XXdp".

Comment: You can refer to [this][1] for more information.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079023/alertdialog-single-choice-item-padding

Comment: android:paddingTop sadly sets the padding for the whole AlertDialog content (so including title, buttons, etc.). android:drawablePadding on the other hand seems to do nothing in this case.

Comment: I think that if you want to change the title and content in the alertdialog you should get the content and title instead of the hole alert. Can you post your code and I can refer to it.